# Tumblr API 401 un authorized error for users API

Tags: tumblr

I am trying to call Users/info from Postman it works perfectly however from application it is returning **401 unauthorized error**

```
this.access_token = auth.authenticate();
map.put("oauth_token", this.access_token);
authorization = auth.generateAuthorizationForMethod("GET", "https://api.tumblr.com/v2/user/info", map);
tumblr.GetUser(authorization);
```

Comment: Are you sure your access_token is getting populated and has the correct value? Are you sure the access_token is being passed in the GET request?

Comment: @GET
 @Path("/user/info")
 public Response GetUser(@HeaderParam("Authorization")String bearer);

Comment: Above is how API looks like, its a get method, i can see the access token populated